Can you colorize the texture of a MeshBasicMaterial white?
Just like you’d set the color of a material to red and it colorizes the material’s texture to red. Is it possible to colorize to complete white? Since applying white as the color is the default to show the texture - I wanted to know if this was possible another way or if the only way is a custom shader.

Have you tried THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({"color": "white"})?
